# Ошибка при запуске gulp с jekill

Tags: gulp, jekyll

Переставил винду на 10ку, взял проект над которым работал на 8ке... все установил вроде... при попытке запустить галп выдает такую ошибку

так же прикладываю свой gulpfile:

```html
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
    prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss   = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    jshint      = require('gulp-jshint'),
    concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
    cp          = require('child_process'),
    jade        = require('gulp-jade'),
    bourbon     = require('bourbon').includePaths;

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};


/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    var pl = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";
    return cp.spawn(pl, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});


/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});


/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'js', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});


/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('css/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [bourbon],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
  .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});


/**
 * Compile Jade
 */
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('_jadefiles/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_includes'));
});


/*
** JS Task
*/
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('js/common.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/js'));
});


/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['js']).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch('_jadefiles/*.jade', ['jade']);
});


/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Текстовый вариант ошибки:

```html
PS G:\Work-FRONT-END\Burger_landing> gulp
[23:58:32] Using gulpfile G:\Work-FRONT-END\Burger_landing\gulpfile.js
[23:58:32] Starting 'sass'...
[23:58:32] Starting 'js'...
[23:58:32] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
[23:58:32] Starting 'watch'...
[23:58:32] Finished 'watch' after 36 ms
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn jekyll.bat ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
PS G:\Work-FRONT-END\Burger_landing>
```

---

[image: скрин с терминала]

Comment: *все установил вроде...* кроме, судя по ошибке, Jekyll. И замените скриншот на текст ошибки, пожалуйста.

Comment: добавил текстовый вариант ошибки, так же хочу заметить что джекил устанавливал.

Comment: Как видно, `gulp` так не считает. У вас команда `jekyll` из этой же командной строки выполняется? Выводит что-нибудь содержательное, не "команда не найдена"?

Comment: Как понятьк команда джекил из той же командной строки? Попробовать запустить чисто джекил?

Comment: Да, именно это.

Comment: Ваша правда, не обратил внимание на то что при установке jekyll выскочила ошибка:

ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, как и было сказано в комментариях ошибка была вызвана тем что Jekyll не был установлен(Именно он выдал ошибку при установке и gulp не находит его для запуска).